# Evaluate the limit of $\arctan(\frac{1}{x - 2})$ where $x \to 2^+$.

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

I'm having trouble understanding what my textbook is saying here. It seems to assign the variable $t$ out of nowhere, and I'm not sure why they do it.

Why assign $t$ to the same equation in $\arctan$?

My textbook says,

> Evaluate the limit of $\arctan(\frac{1}{x - 2})$ where $x \to 2^+$.
>
> If we let $t = 1 / (x - 2)$, we know that $t \to \infty$ as $x \to 2^+$. Therefore, by the formula $\lim_{x \to \infty} \tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 2^+} \arctan(\frac{1}{x-2})= \lim_{t \to \infty} \arctan(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

This is on page 132 of "Calculus: Early Transcendentals", 8th edition, by James Stewart.

Comment: All the book is doing is looking at the same problem through a different lens. You are *defining* $t=1/x-2$; now you ask, what happens to $t$ as $x\to2^+$? Well, you can check that $t\to\infty$. This lets you translate the problem of limits with $x$ to a problem of limits with $t$.

Comment: @Clayton But wouldn't the result of $t$ be different from $\arctan(t)$? Sorry, I'm really confused.

Comment: Well, okay, I realize now that it basically said they would be equal, but I don't get it. Does $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan($<absolutely_any_number_whatsoever>$ ) = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the $t$ for a second. What is going to happen to the fraction $\frac{1}{x-2}$ if $x$ is getting progressively closer to the number $2$ from the right? First of all, the $x$ is going to assume all possible values that are just a tad bigger than $2$: $2.1, 2.01, 2.001, 20001, 2.00001, 2.000001$, etc. When you subtract $2$ from something like $2.000001$, what do you get? You get a number that's going to be very, very small. And what happens when you divide 1 by a very, very small number? The result is going to be a huge number! This means that when $x$ approaches $2$ from the right, the fraction $\frac{1}{x-2}$ is going to positive infinity. And what does the inverse tangent function approach when its argument is going to positive infinity? The answer is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. That's why as $x\rightarrow2^+$, $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x-2}\right)$ goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. This is absolutely equivalent to saying $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\arctan{t}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ because $\frac{1}{x-2}$ in the arctangent function is going to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

If you use
$\arctan(1/x)+\arctan(x)
=\pi/2$,
then
$\arctan(1/(x-2))
=\pi/2-\arctan(x-2)
$.

Since
$\lim_{x \to 0}\arctan(x)
=0
$,
$\lim_{x \to 2}\arctan(x-2)
=0
$,
so
$\lim_{x \to 2}\arctan(1/(x-2))
=\pi/2
$.